# How does one generally express a symmetric summation into matrix multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, summation

In the summation ,$$\sum_{i}^{}\sum_{j}A_{ij}X_{i}X_{j}$$

a nice symmetry exists. The final sum of this summation is just

\begin{matrix}
  (A_{11} & A_{12} & A_{13}) X_{1} \\
  (A_{21} & A_{22} & A_{23}) X_{2} \\
  (A_{31} & A_{32} & A_{33}) X_{3} \\
 X_{1} & X_{2} & X_{3}
 \end{matrix}

where $X_{i}$ is distributed across the elements of the row or column it falls under in the 3 $\times$ 3 matrix of A elements. After this distribution, the resulting 9 elements can be added to give the final sum.

It can be shown that this summation is equal to the matrix product below.

$$\sum_{i}^{}\sum_{j}A_{ij}X_{i}X_{j} = X^{T}AX$$

I've been unable to manipulate the summation $\sum_{i}^{}\sum_{j}A_{ij}X_{i}X_{j}$ into the matrix form above, however. Is there some technique or procedure for this manipulation and, in general, for other such symmetric summations.

Comment: Just use the definition of matrix multiplication: $$\sum_{i}^{}\sum_{j}A_{ij}X_{i}X_{j} = \sum_{i}^{}\sum_{j}X_{i}A_{ij}X_{j} = \sum_iX_i \sum_jA_{ij}X_j = \sum_iX_i[AX]_i = X^T[AX]$$